# Merge tags [composer.json] and [composer-php]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just found the tag [composer.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer.json), and the questions there look pretty similar to those tagged with [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php). Do you think it would make sense to merge them or create a synonym?

**Edit**: Oleg Valter suggested to cross-check postings through `[composer.json] -[php] -[composer-php]`. Through brief scanning, I could not find any posts where [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php) would be definitely wrong, even if I had not used any composer related tag in some of them. To me, it looks like the posts where only [composer.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer.json) is used were tagged so without the users knowing that [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php) would give their posts more visibility.

Comment: We have to check what these 17 questions are about, then I think we are good to go for a synonym: `[composer.json] -[php] -[composer-php]` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer.json+-php+-composer-php)

Comment: [tag:composer.json] seems to be about the Composer's schema, the fact that it is a JSON schema is not very relevant, so it can be fully covered by [tag:composer-php] + [tag:schema] tags. I think [tag:composer.json] should be made a synonym of [tag:composer-php]

Comment: I have only checked a hand full of cases. Looks like a synonym. Also, I could not find any edge-case or counter-example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My vote is to synonymize the tag into [composer-php].

I use Composer. It’s a pretty simple program:

1. You have composer.phar which allows you to run Composer.
2. You start your program by writing a composer.json file, then use it to get all your dependencies. This generates a composer.lock file which is a JSON file listing exactly what was installed.
3. Both of these files are in version control (but your dependencies’ files aren’t) so when you deploy your program you run a command that will tell Composer to use the lock file to replicate the versions of the dependencies that you tested with.

(This works the same way that NPM and Yarn do.)

So, while not all Composer questions involve composer.json, all composer.json questions involve Composer. Looking through all of the questions tagged [composer.json] (but not [composer-php]), it seems that none of them are mistagged and can all just be tagged [composer-php] instead.

Because Composer is so simple and also because the vast majority of Composer questions involve debugging composer.json (but may not be tagged with it), I think it’s not worth having two tags. Plus, this would solve the problem with questions only having the sub tag and falling into obscurity.

Comment: Agreed - one thing I would amend, though, is to keep [tag:composer.json] as a synonym of the main tag. Nothing valuable in the tag itself, but pragmatically speaking, it will prevent it from being recreated ( somebody created in the first place, after all ) and allows questioners to enter whatever they want by silently remapping the tag.

Comment: @OlegValter yeah that sounds good, so I edited.

Comment: thanks  Seems like everything is covered. To other readers: [tag:composer-php] has a request for adding [tag:composer.json] to the list of its synonyms, please vote for it if you agree with the reasoning of the Q&A.

Comment: Approved and merged. Of the 81 tagged [composer.json], only 31 lacked [composer-php], so it wasn't much of a merge overall